# Can I implement IPv6 support on my server using 6to4 address?

Tags: linux, ipv6

I was given an IPv4 address example 192.0.2.4 for my server. To enable clients to reach the server on IPv6 address, I understand that I need to set the AAAA record on my name servers to point to the correct IPv6 address.

Is it possible that I create IPv6 address using 6to4 (example 2002:c000:0204::/48) instead of going through my hosting provider? If so, what are the necessary steps to be taken? If not, why is it not possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can implement IPv6 tunneling with [6to4](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3056.txt), but its use in any scenario other than testing is being [actively discouraged](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-vandevelde-v6ops-harmful-tunnels-01). Before implementing anything on the public Internet, we should consider whether the potentially harmful network effects of an implementation indicate a fault with the solution. I suggest reading [this analysis](https://labs.ripe.net/Members/emileaben/6to4-how-bad-is-it-really) of 6to4 latency issues and the [follow-up](https://labs.ripe.net/Members/emileaben/6to4-why-is-it-so-bad) describing the general brokenness of IPv6 tunneling.

Opinion only: There is no excuse for any provider - transit, colo, hosting or consumer broadband - to not have implemented IPv6 by now, other than apathy or fear of the unknown. The software and hardware support has been in place for years, and it's not like the RIRs are hoarding address allocations. Ask your provider what their native IPv6 implementation timeframe is. If they don't have one, tell them you'll find a provider who already implemented it. There are plenty of them.

Comment: +1 for stop paying providers who haven't implemented IPv6. This is what I do.